# React with webpack not works

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm developing a project with react 18.2.0 and webpack 5.88.2, it works on my localhost, but in the index.html file in the public directory generated by webpack, it doesn't take the app code.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
  <Route path="services" element={<Services />}/>
</Routes>
```

These are the all settings:

src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import Services from './components/pages/Services';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <h1 className="text-left text-yellow-300">Hellol</h1>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
          <Route path="services" element={<Services />}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

build/webpack.base.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    //devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                  loader: "babel-loader",
                  options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                  }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                        "style-loader",
                        { loader: "css-loader", options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
                        "postcss-loader"
                    ]
              },
              {
                /*type: "asset",
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/i,*/
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name:'images/[name].ext',
                        }
                    },
                ],
              }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
    })]
};
```

build/webpack.devp.js

```js
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const base = require("./webpack.base");

/** @type {import('webpack').Configuration} */
const devpConfig = {
    mode: "development",
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
    },
    devtool: "eval-source-map"
}

module.exports = merge(base, devpConfig);
```

build/webpack.pro.js

```js
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const base = require("./webpack.base");

/** @type {import('webpack').Configuration} */
const proConfig = {
    mode: "production",
    devtool: "source-map"
}

module.exports = merge(base, proConfig);
```

src/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--link rel="icon" href="/src/assets/LOGOTIPOico.ico" /-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
    
    <title>Same Day.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "same-day",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config ./build/webpack.pro.js",
    "start": "webpack serve --config ./build/webpack.devp.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.9.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-burger-menu": "^3.0.9",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^3.4.0"
  }
}
```

This is the file generated by webpack.
public/index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
    <title>AA Same Day Garage Door Sarasota.</title>
    <script defer="defer" src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Just load the title from the h1 tag,
but not the rest of the App.js content

I have uninstalled and reinstalled webpack, babel, node and other dependencies, at the beginning it didn't load anywhere, now it only loads on local host, but I can't figure out what to do.